# Add a line break in a table data html

Tags: html

I am trying to add a new line between the btn and the txtbox but nothing worked. I tried 
 , 
 and \n

It is shown as:
[image]

My code:

```
<td>
<div>
<a class="btn btn-default pull-left" style="color: inherit" id="btn">my button</a>
</div>
<div>
 <input id="mytxt" >
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: hi can you use paragraph <p><br></p>

Comment: tried it as well and didn't work

Comment: even with <br>?

Comment: yes doesn't work as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add css padding style in the head:

```
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
#btn-div {
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<td>
<div id="btn-div">
<a class="btn btn-default pull-left" style="color: inherit" id="btn">my 
button</a>
</div>
<div>
<input id="mytxt" >
</div>
</td>
</body>
```

Comment: thanks you but this will change all the divs in the page, which I don't want that to happen

Comment: @SMH then add a CSS class to the div you want to modify

Comment: @SMH just updated the code so that the CSS only applied to a specific id of a div.

Answer (score 2):

This being HTML, your best bet is to either add some CSS to increase the margin/padding on either the bottom of your first `div` or the top of the second one. Alternatively, you could add an empty `div` in between and apply your styles to that.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try inserting between code.

   ```
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
   ```
2. Also, you can try

   ```
   <br />
   ```
3. And my favorite, make a CSS file

   ```
   <html>
   <head>
       <style>
           .gap-10 {
               width:100%;
               height:10px;
           }
           .gap-20 {
               width:100%;
               height:20px;
           }
           .gap-30 {
               width:100%;
               height:30px;
           }
       </style>
   </head>
   <body>

       <!-- this div will give a gap of 10px -->
       <div class="gap-10"></div>

       <!-- this div will give a gap of 20px -->
       <div class="gap-20"></div>

       <!-- this div will give a gap of 30px -->
       <div class="gap-30"></div>

   </body>
   ```

   I hope it helps